# Redirect back to "purchases" page after order completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I've inherited an app which uses the legacy shopify API and I have a hard deadline of August 21st, so I want to avoid updating the API to solve the problem.

We are selling e-documents, and the current purchase process is as follows:

1. User searches and places a product in the cart
2. The User checks out
3. and goes through the purchase process on the Shopify site

This all seems to work fine. What we would like is to redirect the user back to our app with information about the successful purchase (or failure) of the products. As it stands, we don't know what products the user has purchased and we are therefore unable to provide them links to download the documents.

Is there some parameter we can pass to shopify to create that redirect, or do we need to ping the API about past purchases, or is there some other step we are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that what I'm looking for are shopify Webhooks: http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook

It appears that the app is already set up to send order_create and order_payed and all we have to do is capture the data sent to us.

Answer (score 2):

This one is quite easy... Shopify provides you with a textarea element in the admin (checkout and payments) where you can paste code. In this code, you have access to the entire order contents. You can get at this with Liquid.

All you have to do, is render a link to your App and pass the order details to the App via that link. Now your customers will see the Thank You for your purchase, and a button/link to click to complete things as you wish.

Comment: The textarea you're referring to within checkout and payments, is this the "Additional Content & Scripts"?

Just to be clear, are you suggesting writing a little JS snippet that parses the dom and grabs the necessary purchased Shopify elements?

Thanks.

Comment: No need to write JS Snippet. You can just use Liquid as I mentioned.

Comment: David, I don't think this is exactly what we are looking for, but thanks anyway for introducing us to liquid; it's going to come in real handy as we progress through the rest of the app.